# define new class in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, classloader

I want to load new class(not previously loaded) in Tomcat from byte array. I also have reference to tomcat application class loader. 
I declare my custom classloader as

```
class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        super(classLoader);
    }

    public Class loadThisClass(String name){
        //get .class byte array in data.
        Class clazz = defineClass(name, data, 0, data.length, null);
        resolveClass(clazz);
        return clazz;
    }
 }
```

I am using this classloader as

```
CustomClassLoader customClassLoader = new CustomClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
/*
  print getClass().getClassLoader() and it output as
  WebappClassLoader
  context: /test
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
  ----------> Parent Classloader:
  org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@52e99642
*/

Class clazz = customClassLoader.loadThisClass("com.Class1");
//print clazz.getMethods, it print my new method.
```

When i try to check this class as follows

```
Class.forName("com.Class1");
```

I am getting ClassNotFoundException and this class is not accessible to other classes in web application.

**How can i define new class in tomcat web application that is accessible to other classes in my web application.**.

Comment: did you check the name of class?
Any class name provided as a String parameter to methods in ClassLoader must be a binary name as defined by The Java™ Language Specification

Comment: what is the class file name in WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

It may not be enough but don't you need to override `findClass` in your [Classloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findClass-java.lang.String-)?

> protected Class findClass(String name)
>                         throws ClassNotFoundException
>
> Finds the class with the specified binary name. This method should be overridden by
>   class loader implementations that follow the delegation model for
>   loading classes, and will be invoked by the loadClass method after
>   checking the parent class loader for the requested class. ***The default
>   implementation throws a ClassNotFoundException.***

## Response to comment:

The `Prohibited package name : java.lang` implies your trying to load a class in the package space of java.lang from your own class loader. Is either the class loader or the class your trying to load in the package of java.lang?

If not your class loader may be trying to load too much. Within your override of findClass you should check if it is in your domain and throw if not.

```
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) {
   if(!name.startsWith("com.your.package")) throw new ClassNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: I added my custom findClass method and it is working fine in standalone application. But when i try to use this code to load class in tomcat i am getting Exception **Prohibited package name : java.lang**. I think i am getting this error because tomcat WebappClassLoader doesn't delegate to parent classloader. I also use javaassist to dynamically create class which extend from WebappClassLoader and call setDelegate(true) but still getting **Prohibited package**. Do you have any idea about how to load new class in tomcat. I am currently looking into tomcat code on how they load class.

Comment: The `Prohibited package name : java.lang` implies your trying to load a class in the package space of java.lang from your own class loader.

Comment: My class is not in package java.lang. It is in my custom package.  This issue is resolved by skipping classes which start with java. as suggested by David. My purpose is to load new class in tomcat so that other classes loaded by tomcat can also access new class. My approach is to create custom classloader which loads new class by byte array but unfortunately existing classes cannot see new class because it is loaded by child classloader. But this approach is wrong. I am loading new class by calling definesClass method on WebappClassLoader object through reflection.